# As a beginner, I don't understand why this script won't work. Anyone who understands my Google Script problem?

Tags: google-apps-script, syntax-error

```html
function myFunction() {
  var slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides
  for (var i = 0;i<slides.length;++1){
    for (var j = 0;j<slides.length;++j){
  slides[i].insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.DONUT, 10*j, 395, 10, 10)
  if (j<=i){
    var shapes=slides[i].getShapes();
    var lastshape = shapes[shapes.length-1];
    lastshape.getFill().setSolidFill(252, 15, 192)
  }
    }
  } 
}
```

I am a beginner, and for an assignment, I was tasked with creating a script for a google slides presentation using Google Script and was given [this link](https://applieddigitalskills.withgoogle.com/c/middle-and-high-school/en/program-a-progress-bar/program-a-progress-bar/introduction-to-program-a-progress-bar-in-google-slides.html) to base it on. I created it practically line for line (only switching some customizable options), and yet it does not work. This is the script I have made.

However, I keep finding this error code, "SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation line: 3 file: Code.gs", when I try to save it, and I cannot find for the life of me why. Can anyone help me understand the issue with this?

Comment: You need to put an appropriate tag on this (google-app-script?) so the right people will see this. Also include a code sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I thought I added the code, guess I didn't, and I am sorry. I have added the code, and I am adding tags. Thank you for at least checking my post though. You will need to integrate the code into a slides presentation though, as it cannot function with Google Slides

Comment: Fix the indentation too, I think ` slides[i].insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.DONUT, 10*j, 395, 10, 10)`  and the if statement should be indented more

Answer (score 0):

### You have to change your code as the following

I strongly recommend you to take a look into the error message as it usually contains all the necessary information to fix your code.

```
function myFunction() {
  var slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides
  for (var i = 0;i<slides.length; ++i){ // <- Here 1 is not allowed but "i"
    for (var j = 0;j<slides.length;++j){
  slides[i].insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.DONUT, 10*j, 395, 10, 10)
  if (j<=i){
    var shapes=slides[i].getShapes();
    var lastshape = shapes[shapes.length-1];
    lastshape.getFill().setSolidFill(252, 15, 192)
  }
    }
  } 
}
```